# Let $L/K$ be a field extension, s.t $[L:K]>2$, and $\sigma\in Aut(L/K)$ s.t $\sigma$ is of order 2, prove that $L^\sigma\notin\{\mathbb{Q},F_p\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am given a field extension $L/K$ and an automorphism $\sigma \in Aut(L/K)$ such that we define the field $L^\sigma:=\{ x\in L: \sigma(x)=x\}$, then I want to show that for the case when $\sigma$ is of order two and $[L:K]>2$ then $L^\sigma \ne K$ whenever $K$ is either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$.

For the first case, I think it's because the only automorphisms of the rationals identity, and we are given an automorphism which is of order two, i.e not the identity.

But what about the other case of finite field of order $p$?
Thanks!

Comment: It should be greater than 2. fixing it.

Comment: How much Galois theory do you know? $L/L^{\sigma}$ is a Galois extension of degree $2$, and since $[L:K]>2$, we must have $L^{\sigma}\ne K$. It doesn't matter what the field $K$ is.

Comment: @Mark why do we must have: $L^\sigma\ne K$? from what theorem does it follow?

Comment: If $K=L^{\sigma}$, then $[L\colon L^{\sigma}]=[L\colon K]$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist If they were equal then it particular we would have $2=[L:L^{\sigma}]=[L:K]>2$, which is clearly false.